# Warn user to enable TLS prior to redirecting to https - ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, ssl, iis-6

In my ASP.net website, I have a link on my page that requires a https connection.  If a user does not have at least TLS 1.0 enabled in IE, then "Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage".  Is there something that I can do if there is an issue in the redirect that will tell users to enable it before forwarding to the https page?  How do I intercept the issue before they arrive at the IE error?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to go about this differently and test if the client could connect to a https page on my server instead of looking at TLS 1.0 specifically.  Please see my other question:

[Test Client's ability to connect via https - ASP.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20425101/test-clients-ability-to-connect-via-https-asp-net)

JavaScript can be used to attempt to retrieve and image over a secure connection.  If this fails, then I know that the user does not have the correct settings.