# Test Client's ability to connect via https - ASP.net

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, https

I have an ASP.Net page that when the user arrives, I would like to test if they are able to connect to another page on my server via HTTPS connection.  If TLS is not enabled in the user's settings, they are being refused access.

If the test fails, then I would like to display a specific message.

I have considered using:

```
WebClient _client = new WebClient();
```

and

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://myurl....");
```

but these are performing the requests from the server side and therefore they connect without issue even if the client can't connect themselves.

I have also considered an ajax request; however, I cannot make an https request from http because of the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)

Do you all have any ideas that would allow me to test https while on an http page?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an `<img>` tag pointing to a valid image in the HTTPS page, then handle its `load` and `error` events.